# How to apply virtual function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, virtual-functions

In C#, we have concept about abstract method, and how to apply this in Javascript. Example, I have an example:

```
function BaseClass() {
    this.hello = function() {
        this.talk();
    }
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("I'm BaseClass");
    }
};

function MyClass() {
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("I'm MyClass");
    }
    BaseClass.call(this);
};

MyClass.prototype = new BaseClass();

var a = new MyClass();
a.hello();​
```

How the function hello() in BaseClass call the function do() from MyClass when the object is an instance of MyClass. The alert result must be "I'm MyClass". Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant `virtual`/`override`, not `abstract`.

Comment: Yes, the base's function must be a virtual function so that the inherit class can override it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Just remove `BaseClass.call(this);` line and it works, since `this.talk=...` overrides the base method. Or you can start `MyClass` with `BaseClass.call(...)` (at the begining, not the end). But if you are using `call` then there is no need for defining prototype.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to call the "Base" constructor first:

```
function MyClass() {
    BaseClass.call(this);
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("I'm MyClass");
    }
}
```

otherwise `BaseClass.talk` will overwrite `MyClass.talk`.

As a side note, using the concept of "classes" in javascript is rather counterproductive, because this is not how this language works. JS uses prototypal inheritance, that is, you derive new objects from other objects, not from "classes". Also, every function in JS is "virtual" in C++ sense, because its `this` pointer depends on how the function is called, not on where it's defined.

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding your function by doing `BaseClass.call(this);`

```
function MyClass() {
    //BaseClass.call(this); // Not really necessary unless you run code inside your base class
    this.talk = function() {
        alert("I'm MyClass");
    }
};
```

This would make your code work. The `MyClass.prototype = new BaseClass();` should make the hello function available on your `a` object.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are actually defining private instance methods, in both the `MyClass` and the `BaseClass` constructors. This overrides the prototype method lookup, since the `talk` methods are not located in the prototype but are actual instance properties, and the `BaseClass` constructor is invoked *after* the `MyClass` constructor, thus overwriting the `talk` property.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZaKm/) with actual prototype inheritance.